# Downloading Excel File Using Python Selenium

Tags: excel, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i created simple python for downloading excel file from internet, I'm using python and selenium with Chromedriver, the problem is, when download complete and file is saved, i can't read that excel file (tried with Libreoffice, MsExcel), but it can be readed when I manually download that file whitout Selenium, when i tried to read those file using `python xlrd` the error is `zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad magic number for file header`

at first i was think the download is not finished yet because closing the browser too soon, tried to increasing `sleep(20` but the result is the same.

is there anything I have missed in the process that I have been working on?

here is my python script.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def every_downloads_chrome(driver):
    if not driver.current_url.startswith("chrome://downloads"):
        driver.get("chrome://downloads/")
    return driver.execute_script("""
        var items = downloads.Manager.get().items_;
        if (items.every(e => e.state === "COMPLETE"))
            return items.map(e => e.fileUrl || e.file_url);
        """)

uri = "https://cfs.ojk.go.id/cfs/ReportViewerForm.aspx?BankCode=PT.+BPR+Cikarang+Raharja&Month=3&Year=2019&FinancialReportPeriodTypeCode=R&FinancialReportTypeCode=BPK-900-000002"
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")
option.add_argument("--window-size=400,400")
option.add_argument('disable-component-cloud-policy')
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": False,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=option)
browser.get(uri)
timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CFSReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImg"]')))
except TimeoutException:
    browser.quit()

#Download the file by execute JS Command
browser.execute_script("$find('CFSReportViewer').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');")

#wait until download is finish
WebDriverWait(browser, 120,1).until(every_downloads_chrome)

#break 2 second and quit
time.sleep(2)
browser.quit()
```

I'm trying to download excel from this site

```
https://cfs.ojk.go.id/cfs/ReportViewerForm.aspx?BankCode=PT.+BPR+Cikarang+Raharja&Month=3&Year=2019&FinancialReportPeriodTypeCode=R&FinancialReportTypeCode=BPK-900-000002
```

Btw I'm using Mac OS with Chrome `77` and Chromedrive `77.0.3865.40`

here is the case video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N6q66AVpo4XtrZemxoD5E94xUohzcaNx/view

#### Update

It was my environment, I'm using virtualenv ro run this script and got that error message for downloaded file, but when i try to run whitout virtualenv the file can be read without a singel error, that's make me sure that was my virtualenv.

Comment: I tried your code and the excel file can be opened successfully.
Maybe the problem is not "the download is not finished".
You can tried to sleep more seconds to clarify the issue.

Comment: I've add more seconds, and the result remain same, I dont know whats wrong yet. still trying to find out.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem if I change the javascript to clicking the `a` tag

```
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector("[alt=Excel]").click();')
```

Comment: just tried, still can't open saved excel file, btw I'm using Mac OSx, does the operating system version have any effect?

Comment: Maybe though not sure why. I ran twice on Windows no problem. Does your file have an .xlsx extension however?

Comment: Hummmmmm..... I may try running on mac when home though don't really want to install libreoffice.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the operating system version, I've tried on windows as well, but the results still remain the same

Comment: I assume it is something about your environment. Because I ran with your code minus the executable path and added in my line in place of yours for js and it works in repeated runs.

Comment: Maybe though not sure why, I'm using virtual env, I'll explore more about python env then, thanks